# Mule stop and start flow manually keeps a stale consumer and messages are stuck

Tags: java, jms, mule, esb

we have a requirement where we need to stop certain mule flows during maintenance activity (basically to avoid processing any messaging while system is under maintenance). We use following block to stop and a similar block to start once the maintenance is done. The inbound endpoint on this flow is JMS type (using Tibco EMS). Everything works fine, except that sometimes after stop and start, there is one bad consumer, so mule creates one extra consumer. The bad consumer consumes the messages (first time when the message arrives after maintenance) and doesn't deliver. So basically the message is stuck and application never receives this.

Any idea how to resolve this? Are there any better ways to stop consuming messages for certain time - without bringing down the entire application?

```
    for (FlowConstruct flowConstruct : flowConstructs) {
        Flow flow = (Flow) flowConstruct;
        if (flowsToStop.contains(flow.getName())) {
            if(!flow.isStopped()) {
                flow.stop();
            } else {
                logger.warn("Flow " + flow.getName() + " was already stopped!");
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blogpost last week, the basics of how to start and stop flows using Groovy are in there.
http://www.corralict.nl/how-to-start-stop-mule-flows-from-a-client-over-http/

Don't know if this will help with your specific usecase.